# KD-Tree how to delete node/Why is my code not working well

Tags: java, data-structures, kdtree

I was solving a task to find the five nearest neighbors to a point. I was advised to use kd tree.
But there is something wrong with my implementation. I implemented a Kd tree and the only option to search for K neighbors that came to my mind was to find the nearest neighbor, then delete this node and search again. But delete method does not work as expected and removes only part of the values. Class Airport just like a point and have (double) latitude and longitude.
My add methods to build a tree:

```
public void add(Airport airport) { //need to start recursive
    root = addRecursive(root, airport, 0); 
}
private KDNode addRecursive(KDNode current, Airport airport, int depth) {
    if (current == null)
        return new KDNode(airport);
    if (depth % 2 == 0) //Every odd depth we change the axis from x to y
    {
        if (airport.getLatitude() < current.a.getLatitude()) // Compare by x
        {
            current.left = addRecursive(current.left, airport, depth + 1); 
        } else if (airport.getLatitude() > current.a.getLatitude()) 
        {
            current.right = addRecursive(current.right, airport, depth + 1);
        } else {
            return current;
        }
    } else {
        if (airport.getLongitude() < current.a.getLongitude()) // Compare by y
        {
            current.left = addRecursive(current.left, airport, depth + 1); 
        } else if (airport.getLongitude() > current.a.getLongitude()) 
        {
            current.right = addRecursive(current.right, airport, depth + 1);
        } else {
            return current;
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

My delete methods:

```
    private Airport findSmallestValue(KDNode root) {
        return root.left == null ? root.a : findSmallestValue(root.left);
    }


   private KDNode deleteRecursive(KDNode current, Airport airport, int depth) {
        if (current == null)
            return null;

        if (airport == current.a)
        {
            if (current.left == null && current.right == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (current.right == null)
                return current.left;
            if (current.left == null)
                return current.right;
            Airport smallestAirport = findSmallestValue(current.right);
            current.a = smallestAirport;
            current.right = deleteRecursive(current.right, smallestAirport, depth+1);
            return current;
        }

        if (depth % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (airport.getLatitude() < current.a.getLatitude())
            {
                current.left = deleteRecursive(current.left, airport, depth+1);
                return current;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (airport.getLongitude() < current.a.getLongitude())
            {
                current.left = deleteRecursive(current.left, airport, depth+1);
                return current;
            }
        }
        current.right = deleteRecursive(current.right, airport, depth+1);
        return current;
    }

    public void delete(Airport airport) {
        root = deleteRecursive(root, airport, 0);
    }
```

Some examples:
[code main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvsmB.png)
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r2Sg.png)

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example if you want people to understand what your problem is and help you.

Comment: Added a couple of examples

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

The Wikipedia k-d tree page contains a nice explanation on how to implement a k-nearest-neighbours search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree.

## Long answer

Please, do not alter the k-d tree when doing search operations such as searching for the k-nearest-neighbours.

The critical thing to remember is that indexing is costly, especially when preventing the data structure from degradation. We want that the data structure remains unaltered to be able to do several search operations on it. Otherwise, if we have to re-index upon each search, we lose many of the nice features such as the efficient searches that we enjoy with these tree-like structures.

### Additional ideas

- As you have two-dimensional points, why not consider something like a Quadtree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)
- In general, it is always useful to think about how the data is arranged, the kind of searching we want to do with it and take a look at the differences between several data structures (some are more suitable for some specific searches than others). The Wikipedia page for Geometric data structures is a nice entry point. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Geometric_data_structures